# regular expression for not allow minus and decimal numbers and zero in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need regular expression for nopt allowing minus and decimal numbers and zero using javascript. I have code but it is not working. help anyone.

```
$("#hinizio").keyup(function () {
var match = timeRegex.test($(this).val());
alert(match ? 'matches' : 'does not match');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9CVCC/45/

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to match? Examples of input/output might be helpful as your current expression `/^([1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z])*$/gi` would not allow minus symbols, numbers that start with 0 or decimal points.

Comment: but it is not allowing single digit like 1 to 9 and a to z..pls type 5 band check it

Comment: Correct, because your expression explicitly defines that you need to match both of the containing characters groups `[...][...]`. You can resolve this by explicitly not allowing a string of `0` by using `(?!0)` at the beginning of your expression and then combining your two groups into a single one as done in [my response below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37051953/557445).

Answer (score 1):

**Allowing Alphanumeric Characters (But Not 0)**

If you wanted to allow for any number alphanumeric characters without minus symbols `-`, decimal points `.` or just zero as the string, you could use :

```
/^(?!0)[\da-zA-Z]+$/i
```

This will explicitly allow one or more alphanumeric characters, however it will not accept 0 explicitly. You can [see an example of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/es99x9s7/).

**Allowing Only Numeric Characters (But Not 0)**

If you wanted to only allow numbers but not 0, you could use :

```
/^(?!0)\d+$/i
```

You can [see an example of this option here](http://jsfiddle.net/y2s2q0p2/).

Comment: this is allowing only 1 to 9. but it is not allowing greater then 9. Please type 10 or double digit numbers

Comment: Try removing the `g` flag within the expressions (i.e. `/^(?!0)\d+$/i`)

Comment: Ok..but now letters are not allowing..please type like: kl or ty

Comment: You'll need to use the first expression to allow letters `/^(?!0)[\da-zA-Z]+$/i`

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

```
document.getElementById(target).value = newVal.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

The above will remove everything except normal numbers, if you want to keep any special characters, add them to the expression.

Best of all its raw JS, just replace the selector with your current working value from this.

```
$(this).val();
```